# For loop combined with addeventlistener not working (same output)

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm adding click events to li tags in my html. The refresh function I attach to it works fine, just as adding the events. Although the events are all the same..

HTML:

```
<li class="folder" id="css">css</li>
<li class="folder" id="images">images</li>
<li class="folder" id="js">js</li>
```

JS:

```
function addEvent(){
    var dirLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('folder');
    for(i=0; i< dirLinks.length; i++) {
        var tarDir = dirLinks[i].id;
        alert(tarDir);
        dirLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(){refresh('file_manager', 'file-manager.php?tarDir='+tarDir);}, false);
    }
}
```

I want each li tag to click through to a dir that's equal to it's ID. But all the events let me click through to the last found id..(JS) While the alert shows three different ID's..(css, images & js)

What am I doing wrong here? Can't figure it out.

Comment: This is a very common issue for folks learning JavaScript, and unless you know the cause, it is impossible to searchfor.  THe issue is there is only *one* variable with the name `tarDir` and when it changes, all functions that reference it also get the change.   You need to use a closure to give each function a local copy of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing `tarDir` inside a closure, so when you concatenate it you get the last value that has been assigned to it (the value assigned in the last loop iteration). See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for a deep explanation of how closure works.

To solve, you can replace this:

```
dirLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(){refresh('file_manager', 'file-manager.php?tarDir='+tarDir);}, false);
```

with this:

```
dirLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(){refresh('file_manager', 'file-manager.php?tarDir='+this.id);}, false);
```

This works because when the closure is evaluated `this` points to `dirLinks[i]`

This is a working example (I've replaced the call to `refresh` with `alert` only to show that it works): http://jsfiddle.net/fFe8U/1/

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and solution! Works fine and much easier!